# C++ error on linux machine: ccpentium: No input files

Tags: c++, linux

I am writing a code for MRI scanner where all calculation is being done on a Windows machine, while waveforms are being played using linux.

Inside my code, when I declare

```
#include <vector>
```

and try to compile it on linux, I start getting errors like this:

```
ccpentium: FLASH.cpp: No such file or directory
ccpentium: No input files
```

Any help would be appreciated.

More detailed error:

```
export PATH=z:/n4_fsp/tornado/i86/host/x86-win32/bin:C:/WINDOWS/system32:C:/WINDOWS:C:/WINDOWS/system32/Wbem; z:/n4_fsp/tornado/i86/host/x86-win32/bin/ccpentium.exe -O1 -Wall -DTOOL_FAMILY=gnu -DTOOL=gnu -ansi -DVXWORKS  -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -mcpu=pentium -march=pentium -fvolatile -nostdlib -fno-builtin -fno-defer-pop -DCPU=PENTIUM -malign-double -D_CONSOLE -DCEST_OffsetSeries -DBUILD_SEQU -DBUILD_CEST_OffsetSeries -Iz:/n4/pkg -Iz:/n4/tool -Iz:/n4_prod/i86/prod/include -Iz:/n4_deli_vb15a/i86/del
ivery/include -Iz:/n4/x86/prod/include -Iz:/n4/x86/delivery/include -Iz:/n4/pkg/MrServers/MrMPCUSystem/Tornado_i86/target/h -Iz:/n4_extsw/x86/extsw/include -o FLASH.oi86 -c FLASH.cpp
In file included from z:/n4_fsp/tornado/i86/host/x86-win32/lib/gcc-lib/i586-wrs-vxworks/2.9-PentiumIII-010221/include/syslimits.h:7,
                 from z:/n4_fsp/tornado/i86/host/x86-win32/lib/gcc-lib/i586-wrs-vxworks/2.9-PentiumIII-010221/include/limits.h:11,
                 from z:/n4_fsp/tornado/i86/host/x86-win32/include/g++-3/stl_algobase.h:49,
                 from z:/n4_fsp/tornado/i86/host/x86-win32/include/g++-3/algobase.h:36,
                 from z:/n4_fsp/tornado/i86/host/x86-win32/include/g++-3/vector.h:30,
                 from FLASH.cpp:33:
z:/n4_fsp/tornado/i86/host/x86-win32/lib/gcc-lib/i586-wrs-vxworks/2.9-PentiumIII-010221/include/limits.h:117:60: limits.h: No such file or directory
ccpentium: FLASH.cpp: No such file or directory
ccpentium: No input files
ccpentium: FLASH.cpp: No such file or directory
ccpentium: No input files

ccpentium: FLASH.cpp: No such file or directory
ccpentium: No input files
idea_make: *** [FLASH.oi86] Error 1
20:03:23 ERROR sde::fDos:  <idea_make.exe --unix -f CEST_OffsetSeries.mk  i86Release> failed with status=2
20:03:23 ERROR sde idea_make.exe --unix -f CEST_OffsetSeries.mk  i86Release failed
20:03:23 INFO  sde Copying \n4\i86\prod\lib\CEST_OffsetSeries.i86 to c:\Temp\CEST_OffsetSeries.i86
        1 Datei(en) kopiert.
```

Comment: "all calculation is being done on window computer; while waveforms are being played using linux." interesting setup.

Comment: I think it's a matter of fix a wrong file path: z:/n4_fsp/tornado/i86/host/x86-win32/lib/gcc-lib/i586-wrs-vxworks/2.9-PentiumIII-010221/include/limits.h on FLASH.cpp

Answer (score 2):

The error is caused by the combination of

```
-nostdlib
```

flag which asks the compiler not to use its standard linking environment and missing files from your include paths.

From very recent experience, I was missing two files from the include:

```
-Iz:/n4/pkg/MrServers/MrMPCUSystem/Tornado_i86/target/h
```

Eventually, I manually copied them from an updated version, but I do not know whether this is a bug or a 'feature' of the older version, so it still remains to be tested whether the compiled code does not break the scanner.